# Nest.js assets do not changes on save

Tags: nestjs, hot-reload, nestjs-config

I tried to use `hbs` files with nest.js, this is my nest-cli.json:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src/modules",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "assets": [
      {
        "include": "**/views/*.hbs",
        "outDir": "dist/modules",
        "watchAssets": true
      },
      {
        "include": "**/views/*.html",
        "outDir": "dist/modules",
        "watchAssets": true
      }
    ],
    "watchAssets": true,
    "deleteOutDir": true,
    "manualRestart": true
  }
}
```

On first start nest copy all `hbs` files to right places, but I cannot make nest watch `hbs` files, so when I changing them in dev mode server is not restarting...

I spend 3days in google, aske chatgpt and have no idea what can I do to make it works.